# Change Household contact to Organization contact

Tags: contacts, contact-types, 4.6.3

A staff member added quite a few contacts as Households but they should have been added as Organizations. I can find no form control to switch the contact type to Organization. Can you suggest a procedure to fix this or should we just redo the work?

This not exactly a duplicate of [this question](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/20/how-can-i-change-the-contact-type-for-one-contact-to-from-individual-household) because we are going from Household to Organization, and there is no concept of merging a Household into an Organization (as far as I know).

Comment: Seems like the solution offered at the other question would work for you - it tells how to change one type of contact into another, isn't that what you want to do?

Comment: @Coleman -- the other answer is annoyingly ambiguous in it's definition of terms -- mathematically it's herding cats. I would need an exact set of steps to reproduce the solution. When he says "Manually navigate to this URL", which URL is it exactly? You gotta say. And there is no "HOUSEHOLDID" or "INDIVIDUALID" to manipulate, at least in the affordances I see on the forms or URLs for either the household or new organization contact. I wish it were that simple. I need it explained like I am five :+>

Comment: I have tried to address your concerns by editing the answer to the other question. One thing to remember is that cid = "contact id for the record you want to keep" and oid = "contact Id for the record you want to merge then delete".  So for you cid needs to be the contact Id of the organisation you create ( it just needs a name, no other details) and oid will be the contact id of the household you are going to "convert" into an organisation.

Comment: Thanks I got it to work. The URL for the merge action doesn't look like that on wordpress but I figured it out. It's still a lot of work. You have to remember to check the address box on merge form to copy that over.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turns out that exporting the problem household contacts and then importing them as organization contacts, using the appropriate field mappings, is the fastest way to do this. After import just delete the household contacts.

Comment: Yoiu should mark this as answered