# Moving contribution from individual to organization

Tags: duplicate-contacts, contact-types

I have a contact in CiviCRM that is of contact-type Individual in CiviCRM. In real life, this is an organization.

I want to convert this contact from an Individual to an Organization. How do I do that?

(I could just delete the contact, and create a new contact, but I really want to keep the contribution history. So then I would need to move that from one contact to another. Using merge contacts only works within same contact-type. So this solution doesn’t seem to work either)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [how can I change the contact type for one contact (to/from individual/household/organization)?](https://civicrm.stackexchange.com/questions/20/how-can-i-change-the-contact-type-for-one-contact-to-from-individual-household)

Comment: @JonG-MegaphoneTech this was really helpful, I will check that out!

Comment: i think the Contact Editor extension should be added as a direct answer on this Q. Happy to do so but the credit belongs to JonG

Answer (score 4):

Run below query in mysql

```
UPDATE civicrm_contact
SET contact_type = 'Organization',
organization_name = sort_name
WHERE id = 123;
```

123 is a contact id

Comment: Isn’t there a non-code way of doing this?

Comment: As Jon said contact editor extension is another option to do so, if its a matter of updating more than one contact.

Answer (score 4):

Alternatively - you can try install/use:

https://civicrm.org/extensions/move-contribution